# How to deploy a Socket.io React app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, socket.io

I am attempting to deploy a working locally socket.io web app to Heroku. Every time I try to connect, the console indicates the following error:

`https://localhost:9090/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MgLhhNr net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

My server has the following code:

```
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Socket listening on PORT: `)
})
```

and then my React component starts with:
`this.socket = io();`

Any help or at least an indication of where to look would be extremely helpful. I've gone through the Heroku socket.io guide and it doesn't seem to be working still

Comment: where is your socket.io backend hosted ?

Comment: Why you connect to `https://localhost:9090` instead of Your Heroku app endpoint? Try my snippet code with your value `this.socket = io("YOUR_HEROKU_APP_URL");`

Comment: I think I'm answering your questions correctly in stating that my front and backend are being hosted together, or I'm trying for them to be. When I'm running it locally, its all being run on my local machine. When I use heroku, I'm able to connect to my database and do all of that, but the errors only come up with the portion of my app that uses socket. io.

I've also attempted the above fix and it doesn't change anything as far as I can tell

Comment: The issue ended up being my folder structure. Once that was fixed I was able to deploy.